# How do I curl the .jar for cljsjs/react?

Tags: clojure, reactjs, clojurescript, reagent

I'm following the [Clojurescript Quick Start](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start), and I'm continuing to build out a clojurescript project without relying on a build tool like lein or boot to make sure I understand what is really happening.

I'm at a point where I'm trying to introduce a dependency on reagent, which itself has a few dependencies like [cljsjs/react](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/tree/master/react) and [cljsjs/react-dom](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/tree/master/react-dom).  The instructions within the quick start related to cljsjs dependencies is [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Dependencies#cljsjs), and the example given `curl`s `clojars.com` for the `.jar`.  This does not work for `cljsjs/react`, as there is no `.jar`.  Can someone please explain:

- how I can move forward without a build tool like lein/boot
- why there is no `.jar`
- and what is actually occurring here?

To get reagent to work, I was able to clone the reagent repo and run `lein compile` and `lein uberjar` to get a `.jar` that I could place in the root of my project and build with `java -cp cljs.jar:reagent-0.6.0.jar:src clojure.main build.clj`, but I'm at a loss for this react dependency.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should be able to find the jars in your maven repository. For example on my machine they are under `C:\Users\Chris\.m2`. Build tools such as lein and sbt sit atop the maven repository. Normally you don't have to fetch jars out from them.

Comment: Another place to look is in this directory off your project root: `resources\public\js\out\cljs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
curl -O https://clojars.org/repo/cljsjs/react/0.14.0-1/react-0.14.0-1.jar
```

Rinse and repeat for react-dom.

That said for any real work you are almost certainly going to want either [Boot](http://boot-clj.com/) or [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) with [CLJSBuild](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild)

Comment: Huh.  I wonder if I had a typo in the url or something.  Thanks.